# How to give uniform space in java while using nested loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm creating a program with nested loops to produce the following output:

> ```
>     1
>    22
>   333
>  4444
> 55555
> ```

The problem with my current code is, that the output isn't exactly aligned as it should be:

> ```
>    1
>   22
>  333
>  4444
> 55555
> ```

My code is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 5; j >= i; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I have already tried usind regular space `System.out.print(" ")` for giving space.

Comment: Can you do three things for use? 1) Please try to format your code properly. 2) please remove all the duplicated text snippets you have in your question. It is currently hard to read. 3) show us your currently used code.

Comment: public class net{  
 public static void main(String[] args){  
  for(int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)<br />
  {<br />
   for(int j = 5; j>=i; j--) <br />
   { <br />
    System.out.print(" "); <br />
   }<br />
   for(int k = 1 ; k <= i ; k++) <br />
   {<br />
    System.out.print(i);<br />
   }<br/>
   System.out.println("");<br/>
  }<br/>
 }<br/>
}<br/>

Comment: Please edit the question and put formatted code in there, not the comments.

Comment: how to give space at the end of line while wrting here ??

Comment: I edited your question to fix the formatting. You can check its [source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0bb13af9-abbf-40b7-b7e3-c81402476425/view-source) to see how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.out.print("%5.d\n",x);

Comment: it says not suitable method for using in (String int). however my code runs correctly in Ecllipse but not in Scite. @David Pulse

Comment: This will adjust everything to the nth (5) digit. It will put them in as you want them,  and they'll be right justified.

Comment: Try `%6.d` and you can add precision by putting a digit on the right of the d